# Error while opening a package in java

Tags: package

```
import C.Users.mihir.Downloads.IntroNeuralJavaExampesEdition2.JavaIntroNeuralNetworkEdition2.src.com.heatonresearch.book.introneuralnet.neural.matrix;

public class test1 {
    public test1() {
    }

    public class Test {
        public Test() {
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            boolean b= BiPolarUtil.double2bipolar(2);
                    System.out.println(b);
        }
         double matrixdata={{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0}};
         double mat=new Matrix(matrixdata);
    }
}
```

Error:

> package
>   C.Users.mihir.Downloads.IntroNeuralJavaExampesEdition2.JavaIntroNeuralNetworkEdition2.src.com.heatonresearch.book.introneuralnet.neural
>   does not exist
>       cannot find symbol class Matrix        illegal initializer for double
>         cannot find symbol class Matrix

Comment: hey i m a fresher at programming i wanted to ask how to set the classpath since i couldnt import a certain file due to name error and now even i cant ask questions because i m banned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This import looks wrong:

```
C.Users.mihir.Downloads.IntroNeuralJavaExampesEdition2.JavaIntroNeuralNetworkEdition2.src.com.heatonresearch.book.introneuralnet.neural.matrix;
```

This isn't how you should be importing a custom class. You're getting this error because Java can't find it. You'd normally not specify a full path in the `import` statement, and allow Java to search your `CLASSPATH`.

Read [this](http://suite101.com/article/how-to-create-a-java-package-a91474), as an example of creating and using custom packages.